# Singular inconsistent scalar system when connecting a pressure boundary

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to add a pressure boundary to my pipe and get the following error during initialization:

```
Error: Singular inconsistent scalar system for 
pipe.h_out = ((if boundary.m_flow > 0.0 then pipe.volume.h else 0.0)-pipe.h[...])/( -(if boundar.m_flow > 0.0 then 0.0 else 1.0)) = 2.38651e-009/-0
HandleRoot:HandleRoot
```

[...] -> Too long for output in the consol i think

Anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve this? I am calculating the pressuredifference with a function for dp out of massflow. Could it be that?

*Additional Informations:*

I am using Dymola with the Library ClaRa. The model in question is a pipe model with the volume splitter for thermal inertia "ClaRa.Components.VolumesValvesFittings.Fittings.SplitVLE_L2_flex". The model is build up from two pressure boundaries. One connecting to a supply pipe and one to the return pipe. The ends of the pipes are connected over the volume to two simple consumer models with each of them having a valve to control the return temperature.

**Update:**
I reduced the error to:

```
The following error was detected at time: 0
Error: Scalar system is always singular for supply_pipe.volume.p = (0.0)/(0.0) = 0/0
FixInitials:Init
```

Which only happens when i connect the second consumer to the supply/return pipe. The model computes with only one consumer.

Changing the pressurloss model to one that calculates the massflow from given pressure doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: Difficult to help with this little information. Important information to add would be:
(1) which tool are you using, 
(2) which library, 
(3) information about the model (screenshot, code...), 
(4) anything else that could help...

Comment: Added additonal informations

Comment: eL3ctric, please attach a model so that the community can reproduce the error and help you solve the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem.

I've had a resistance to resistance connection between the pipes and a shorting between the connectors. 
Creating another pipe with a volume model at the beginning instead of the end solved it.